# How to have the filter/find method return an object field in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an object array with something called animalData

```
animalData {
 type:"cat",
 object: SmallAnimal
 }
```

Given a list of animalData, I want to find for the first one called "cat" and return `animalData.object`. What would I need to add to the statement below to retrieve animalData.object?

```
this.animals.find((animalData) => animalData.type == "cat");
```

Comment: If you have an array with multiple cats you can also do `animals.filter(x => x.type === "cat").map(x => x.object)` which will return an array of all `object`s  for cats

Answer (score 0):

`find` will return the first instance of `animalData` which matches the predicate - if you want a property of that object just read it:

```
const firstCat = this.animals.find((animalData) => animalData.type == "cat").object;
```

It may well be `undefined` if your `find` does not return a result.